# Ubuntu16.04.3 Kernel Panic Error

Tags: 16.04, kernel, shutdown

below is the specs:

Desktop:alienware-aurora-r6
Ubuntu 16.04.3 Kernel: 4.10.0-32-generic

I am able to reboot the system but I am not able to shut it down. The system hangs with the following error messages until I press my power button. Please refer to the attached image of the screen shot.

> Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal Exception in interrupt

[image: Kernel panic screenshot image]

Any advice on how to solve this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Confirm that `intel-microcode` is installed... `dpkg -l intel-microcode | grep ii`. Also, describe your SSD/HDD configuration. If SSD, describe make/model #.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for the comments. I ran the dpkg command and no packages found matching intel-microcode. Disk config is 256 PCIe SSD (system) + 1TB SATA HDD (storage). Not able to retrieve info for SSD seems ubuntu cannot recognize the brand and model. Weird. System running okay on SSD.

Comment: Since you have Intel processors, install `intel-microcode` with `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install intel-microcode`. Use `sudo lshw -C disk` and see if it'll tell you about the SSD... at lease the model #, and maybe the manufacturer... then go to the manufacturer's web site and check for updated firmware... very important. You should also check for an updated BIOS for your computer.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks. I installed the microcode and lshw only shows my 1T Seagate HDD. I tried sudo parted -l, it shows the SSD but model unknown with only a serial number (only numbers cannot figure out brand). I will try other ways to figure out the SSD model. Unfortunately I dont have a windows on my machine. Thanks.

Comment: Is this a desktop machine? Is the 256 PCIe SSD visible that you can find a make/model # on it?

Comment: @heynnema ya is Dell desktop. I found the SSD model from Dell website and its SanDisk A400. I guess it is visible by ubuntu since I installed the ubuntu on this SSD and sudo parted -l can see it. But Ubuntu can not detect the model of the SSD and it is shown unknown model.

Comment: but lshw cannot see the SSD i have no idea why. Is it because it's the system partition?

Comment: It can't see it because it's PCIe. Now take that make/model # over to the SanDisk web site and find out if there's a firmware update for it. Do the same for your BIOS.